# Pipe variable from a Bash file into a JQ command in another Bash file

Tags: json, bash, jq

### Goal

Pipe variable from a Bash file into a JQ command in another Bash file

### Context

I have a JSON file with two empty values I want to populate with:

- An HTML file
- A variable in a Bash file (file-b.sh)

The HTML portion works. I cannot figure out the variable portion. I show the HTML portion to demonstrate the logic I'm attempting to follow.

#### file-a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#This line (for the HTML portion) works:
jq --arg text "$(<file.html)" '.content.text=($text | @html)' my-json.json > file.json

# This line (for the Bash variable) doesn't...see end of question for result:
jq --arg variable "$subject" '.subject=$variable' file.json > file-1.json
```

#### file-b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

subject="abc"
export subject
./file-a.sh
```

#### file-1.json: The result

The result is that `content.text` is populated, while `subject` is printed literally as the variable I attempted to code.

```
{
  "content": {
    "text": "Is populated; works great"
  },
  "subject": "$subject",
}
```

Based on what I have read, I have tried many iterations of single quotes, double quotes, parentheses, curly brackets (e.g., `{"$subject"}` or `".subject=$variable"`), `echo` in a pipe, but continue to fail. Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Did you make sure to you use double quotes around `$subject` in `--arg variable "$subject"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't need two bash scripts. You can call file-a.sh with an argument:

```
./file-a.sh "This is my subject"
```

and within file-a.sh you can access the argument as:

```
echo "Subject: $1"
```

... where $1 , $2  etc are the variables